# How to make a folder landing-page looks like the initial-page of a sub-site in a Plone portal?

Tags: python, plone, html, portal

As a CMS, Plone receives contents and display these contents organized by menus in an initial "home" page, where you can browse other pages and other types of contents.

Is it possible to make a menu item to point to a **second** home page in the same plone portal?

**Today I discovered that we can select a page or other type of content to replace the landing page of a folder. It's almost what I want. If I could make this page to show the news from that folder, and some other contents well designed in table like the "Initial page", that would be the goal. I believe I would need a portlet to make a new kind of content or make the 'page' to mimic an 'initial page'**

It is different from creating a simple page linked to that menu, where there will be only lists of contents and widgets at most.

The case study is a Plone portal of an government office, and the subsection that wants to have it's own "home index" is the human resources division.

I need a real new 'home' page as if it was a home for an entire (and important) subsection of my portal.

If it is possible, will I need only administrator skills or will I have to alter some python code or config file?

[image]
*This is the initial (home) page, the index of the Plone portal*

[image]
*This is the standard page of a menu root, having the content list for it's submenu items*

Comment: The case study is a Plone portal of an government office, and the subsection that wants to have it's own "home index" is the *human resources* division.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What you mean with "*And all the content can be accessed by a main menu and there is a home page where everything is mounted.*"? How you site's home page is done right now?

Comment: @keul I have edited the question, I hope it is more objective now.

Comment: Sorry but still not clear: how do you created the "home" view? Maybe you are using a 3rd party product. Try to see what view or default contents is used in the Plone site root.
Maybe you are using a product like collective.porteltpage or collective.cover, or others

Comment: I'd agree with @keul .... it seems that our terminology is a bit unclear. You probably just want a new portal page (asking for a "home page" makes us Plonistas think of a new Navigation Root - but I don't think you want that).  Can you view the source of the page & copy the body tag?  It will look something like this: `<body class="template-view portaltype-collective-cover-content site-myintranet section-welcome-to-mysite userrole-manager userrole-authenticated userrole-owner">`

Comment: Sorry, english please! "plonistas" isn't an indication of my skill in Portuguese

Comment: Again I have edited to explain it with more details. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I would say that we need a subsite for the human resources, which has it's own landing page, but the contents and access session is still integrated with the main site.

Comment: We contacted a former employee that stored a portlet made by him with that page.

Comment: It is unfinished but when I do I will put the answer here.

Answer (score 2):

This may well be possible. What you are really asking for is a "portal like view" on another folder in Plone.  This doesn't come as standard in Plone, so what you've got working on the homepage indicates either:

a) you have an addon such as collective.portletpage or collective.cover (as @kuel suggested)
b) a Plone developer has set you up a custom view for your homepage

If it is b) then you will probably need help to tweak it to your needs for the HR folder, otherwise you should be able to do most of what you want on your own, by just adding a "Cover" or "PorletPage" (or ....)  type as the default page for the HR folder.

The reason we are struggling to give you a perfect  answer is that we don't know *which* addon or custom view you are using for your homepage. This is why I asked for the body tag.  To get that (assuming you are using Firefox) just right click on the page and select "View Page Source", then press Ctrl-F for the Find menu and type body into that field.  Just copy 4 or 5 lines around there to let us help you more!

Alternatively (though less certain to work) just click on the "Add New..." menu and list what types are available and we may be able to tell you what type to add.

Comment: Look, I checked the HTML and the body tag is just <body>. What does that mean?

Comment: I am pretty sure that the developer used a custom view and he is no longer in the team. :-(

Comment: That's surprising, are you sure? (it's not the closing <body/> tag for instance).  If so, then I would say you do need developer help. What's under the "Add new..." menu?

Comment: Maybe he is using Diazo.

Comment: @keul it occurred to me, but then I found it hard to envisage theming without  classes in the body tag

Comment: @EASI did you solve this? OR can you say what types are available in the "Add new ...." menu?

Comment: We used a solution from a former employee... as soon as I implement it I will answer it here.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is really well implemented by collective.cover addon: https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/#don-t-panic

It's used by many brazilian federal government websites such as Brasil.gov.br, Planalto.gov.br, Secom.gov.br and also by the project https://identidade-digital-de-governo-plone.readthedocs.org/

Also you should join PloneGovBR community: https://colab.interlegis.leg.br/wiki/PloneGovBr

Happy Ploning! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Products.ContentWellPortlets to assign additonal elements above and below the landing page. In case you don't want an element in the middle of the grid-/dashboard-like layout (similar to http://[HOST]/[PLONESITE_ID]/@@dashboard), leave all fields of the landing page empty, but the required title, and hide the title via CSS.

Answer (score -3):

EASI.

You should only try this if you have Zope administrator access.

Go to the URL:

```
/portal_skins/plone_login/logged_in/manage
```

In there you will see a line of code identifying the user:

```
member = membership_tool.getAuthenticatedMember()
```

Copy that line.

Now go to the URL:

```
/portal_skins/plone_login/login_next/manage
```

...and click on the Customize button.  This will give you an override copy of "login_next" that you can edit.  (At any point you can delete this copy and you will revert to the original.)

Now look at the end of the routine where a line begins with:

```
state.set(came_from=came_from, next=next)
```

You will see a variable ***next*** being set to the URL that the server will go to next.  Now if you paste your ***member = ...*** line just before that, you can set the variable "next" to the HR homepage URL, for cases where member is in HR.

There is probably a Group to which HR people belong, but that's a slightly different question.  Please see docs at: `http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/members/member_basics.html`

Remember, just delete your customized copy of login_next to revert to the original.

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a "portal like view" of a folder. Your answer is about the initial page people see on login - which might be useful, but doesn't answer the question as I see it

Comment: If that's right I have misunderstood.  I had thought that the case was that a different home page was to be rendered for HR people.  I appreciate that it could be impossible to answer without knowing the exact configuration of EASI's intranet.

Comment: How reliable would portal_properties/site_properties/default_page be at IDing the home page on a Plone site?